# Timestamp in html

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to store a timestamp in my database. HTML code:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST"/>

<style>
p{
    float:center;
}
</style>


<Font color=red > <center>Support or Analysis Tracker (SoAT) </center></Font>
</br>
</br>

<p align="left">
<label for="PROCESS"><FONT color=default>Analysis/Support</label> &nbsp</t>
 <select id="PROCESS" name="PROCESS">
<option value="Analysis">Analysis</option>
<option value="Support">Support</option>
</select> 
    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<label for="SO_NUMBER"><FONT color=default>SO_Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="SO_NUMBER" name="SO_NUMBER"  value ="SO_" required/>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <label for="PERSON_INCHARGE"><FONT color=default>Person_Incharge</label>
  <input type="text" id="PERSON_INCHARGE" name="PERSON_INCHARGE" required/></br>
</br></br>
</br>
</p>
<p align="left">
    <label for="DESCRIPTION"><FONT color=default>Description</label>
    <input type="text" id="DESCRIPTION" name="DESCRIPTION" />

</p>

</br>
    </br>
<div style="text-align:center"> 
<button>

   <img alt="ok" src=
   "http://www.blueprintcss.org/blueprint/plugins/buttons/icons/tick.png" /> 

INSERT
  </button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

After hitting the insert button, I need to store the current time and date in the database. The backend database structure is as following:

[image: Database structure]

Comment: `echo date(y-m-d h:i:s);`

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: its inputting null in the database

Comment: use PHP date function **date('Y-m-d G:i:s')** for timestamp

Comment: You have a *lot* of errors in that HTML. Use a validator: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Answer (score 0):

In these cases you can use from now() function of mysql.

```
Insert INTO tablename(RECEIVED) VALUES(now())
```

with this structure it use from mysql server date and time

Comment: when you want to run query of insert you can use from now() function of mysql. this function will return current date and time of mysql server

Comment: $value1 =$_POST['SO_NUMBER'];
 $value2 =$_POST['PROCESS'];
 $value3 =$_POST['PERSON_INCHARGE'];
 $value4 =$_POST['DESCRIPTION'];
 $value5 =$_POST['RECIVED'];
 $value6 =$_POST['SENT'];

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO SO_T (SO_NUMBER, PROCESS, PERSON_INCHARGE, DESCRIPTION, RECIVED,  SENT) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5','$value6')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

Comment: this is the query i am running

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO SO_T (SO_NUMBER, PROCESS, PERSON_INCHARGE, DESCRIPTION, RECIVED, SENT) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', now(),'$value6')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));